# xcode slave now reports HTTP response code 400

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild, cloudbees

Never had a problem before executing my xcode slave via java -jar jenkins-cli.jar on CloudBees.  I get the following error response in the console window

```
WILs-MacBook-Pro:tmp WPANNELL$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://ventana.ci.cloudbees.com -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa customer-managed-slave -fsroot ~/jenkins -labels xcode -executors 4 -name mobile-slave

Enter passphrase for /Users/WPANNELL/.ssh/id_rsa:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://ventana.ci.cloudbees.com/cli
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:77)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:155)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:139)
    at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:68)
    at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:438)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:373)
WILs-MacBook-Pro:tmp WPANNELL$
```

Have you seen this kind of response before?

Comment: Updated: We have rolled back to the least release of DEV@cloud where this is fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience. ---------
When was the last time you successfully connected? We are hunting down this problem and knowing when it started happening would be a big help.